# CSS animation started via JS not working with Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, css-animations

I'm using a simple CSS animation to create a fade-in effect based on opacity. The animation is started via JS in order to wait until the browser completed loading. It does work with Firefox and Chrome, but does not start with Safari. Interestingly, it also does work with Safari locally, i.e. if the browser loads website data that is saved onto my computer locally! It does not work with Safari if the website data is loaded from an external server.

I found out that the animation also starts with an external server involved if I let Safari display "web information" or set the "responsive design" mode!

I could test it with Safari 9 and 11 (and cleared cache). I could not find any existing threads addressing this or a similiar issue. Thank you in advance!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>test</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
   <script src="js-script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<main>
   <div id="fading">
   Test
   </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#fading {
   /* shorthand notation not always working with Safari */
   -webkit-animation-name: fadein;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
   -moz-animation: fadein 5s ease-in;
   -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
   -o-animation: fadein 5s ease-in;
   -o-animation-play-state: paused;
   animation: fadein 5s ease-in;
   animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0}
  to   { opacity: 1}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0}
  to   { opacity: 1}
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0}
  to   { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0}
  to   { opacity: 1}
}
```

JS:

```
"use strict";

function start() {
   var fading = document.getElementById("fading");
   fading.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
   fading.style.mozAnimationPlayState = "running";
   fading.style.oAnimationPlayState = "running";
   fading.style.animationPlayState = "running";
}

window.onload = start;
```

Comment: You mean it never works? Even if you clear the cache? One workaround you may try is to trigger a reflow at the beginning of your js function (`var fading = document.getElementById("fading"); fading.offsetWidth;` should do). But what you describe (works on localhost) seems odd. Also, always set the spec compliants rules last, even in js.

Comment: Yes, cache is cleared. I edited the js script (and my post) and set the spec compliant rule last. I also tried the reflow approach that you proposed. But anmiation is still not starting with Safari externally.

Comment: ... interesting. And can you make it work from the dev tools? Also do you have CSS errors that get reported?

Comment: HTML and CSS are validated. But I found out that I can make the animation start if I let Safari display "web information" or set the "responsive design" mode!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided for a different approach finally using CSS transitions. This seems to be more appropriate for js-started fading effects and does not show the Safari issue described above. In addition, JS and CSS need less lines of code.

CSS:

```
#fading {
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
   -o-transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
   transition: opacity 5s ease-in;
}
```

JS:

```
"use strict";

function start() {
   var fading = document.getElementById("fading");
   fading.style.opacity = 1;
}

window.onload = start;
```